# How does angular universal SSR build flow works and how to customise web-pack server config like reducing CSS class names at the compilation time?

Tags: angular, webpack, server-side-rendering

I generated angular application with angular cli and added angular universal to the project

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject some-amazing-project
```

On adding angular universal few files are updated and some new created.

**updated package.json**

```
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run some-amazing-project:server:production"
```

**Build Folder Structure**

[image]

**breaking the npm scripts for production build**

`ng build --prod` : It generates the dist/browser folder with polyfill, main, common, runtime and other module chunks js files, index.html and styles.{randowmno}.css file.

`ng run some-amazing-project:server:production` : It generates the dist/server folder with main.js file.

`webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors` : generates the final dist/server.js file.

**webpack.server.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  entry: {
    server: './server.ts'
  },
  target: 'node',
  resolve: { extensions: ['.ts', '.js'] },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  },
  output: {
    // Puts the output at the root of the dist folder
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
      {
        // Mark files inside `@angular/core` as using SystemJS style dynamic imports.
        // Removing this will cause deprecation warnings to appear.
        test: /(\\|\/)@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/).+\.js$/,
        parser: { system: true },
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ]
};
```

How can I change classname to reduce bundle size, I tried css-loader/style-loader, but don't know what should be the entry point, 
If I set `optimization: { minimize: true}` as `true` it application throws error on build.

For an independent project I followed [this article](http://this%20https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/this-is-how-angular-cli-webpack-delivers-your-css-styles-to-the-client-d4adf15c4975) and it worked fine, just want to know how the build flow works in angular ssr.

Comment: what is the error that you are getting on build?

Comment: @gautamsiva `TypeError: StaticInjectorError(r)[InjectionToken Application Initializer -> InjectionToken DocumentToken]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[InjectionToken Application Initializer -> InjectionToken DocumentToken]: 
    Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object` this error comes if I set  
`optimization: {
    minimize: true
  },` on `false` it works fine

Comment: I just setup angular SSR seed project with bootstrap 4 and tried to follow the steps, the classes are just showing as normal not the reduced classname one.

Comment: Hi there, are you using domino for rendering window,document in dom?

Comment: if yes, its because of domino that you are getting 'instanceof' error,try removing that and add if(isplatformBrowser) in your code at the time of document,window execution.Also if you need to reduce the main.js file,give optimization : {scripts: true, styles :true} under server in angular.json or simply give optimization: true there